# Sorting in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I would like to sort my result by using the DetailRefNumber.  However, I could not achieve to sort like

```
2.1 
2.2 
2.3 
xxx
xxx
2.10
2.11
2.12
```

Could you please guide me how I could do it?

[image]  Thanks.

Comment: What type is `DetailRefNumber`?

Comment: What is its type?  Please dont say char / varchar / nvarchar

Comment: Unfortunately, it is varchar(20)

Comment: @TTCG - I thought so...the question is why is it varchar?

Comment: @marc_s, Yes, it will solve the problem.  But the data are imported from the external datasource and there are about 50,000 records in the system.  :(

Comment: Can you explain your sort order?  **As it is it makes no sense.**

Comment: @JNK think of version numbers: 1.1, 1.2, .. 1.9, 1.10, 1.11 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `PARSENAME`

```
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(DetailRefNumber,2) AS INT),CAST(PARSENAME(DetailRefNumber,1) AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help.  You guys give me a lot of alternative ideas and knowledge.  I really appreciate your help and contributions.  Thanks Millions.

Answer (score 5):

If that `DetailRefNumber` will **always** be a number, separated by a dot, you could add two computed columns to that table which basically take that column apart into two separate, numeric values:

```
alter table dbo.YourTable
  add RefNrMajor AS CAST(LEFT(DetailRefNumber, CHARINDEX('.', DetailRefNumber) - 1) AS INT) PERSISTED

alter table dbo.YourTable
  add RefNrMinor AS CAST(SUBSTRING(DetailRefNumber, CHARINDEX('.', DetailRefNumber) + 1, 999) AS INT) PERSISTED
```

and now you can order by those new numeric columns:

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY RefNrMajor, RefNrMinor
```

Comment: +1 I didn't notice the "version" number sorting, so this definately does it.

Answer (score 3):

I've <strike>never</strike> just tried this but can you try to `CAST` or `CONVERT` a column in the order by?

Try this...

```
SELECT
 ...
FROM
...
ORDER BY
 CAST(MyColumn AS Decimal(18,2))
```

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
 (
  mycol varchar(20)
 )

INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('1.0')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('1.10')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.10')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('21.20')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.00')

SELECT * FROM #t ORDER BY CAST(mycol as Decimal(18,2))

DROP TABLE #t
```

[image]

Your's would become:

```
SELECT
   AssessmentID,
   AssessmentRefNumber,
   DetailRefNumber
FROM 
   Assessments
ORDER BY
   CAST(DetailRefNumber As Decimal(18,2))
```

## edit

Just noticed the "version number sorting".
Take exactly what I did and change the final part to use substring / what marc_s posted works pleasantly:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
 (
  mycol varchar(20)
 )

INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('1.0')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('1.2')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('1.11')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.10')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('21.20')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.20')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.00')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.11')
INSERT INTO #t(mycol) VALUES('2.2')

SELECT 
   * 
FROM #t 
ORDER BY 
  CAST(LEFT(mycol, CHARINDEX('.', myCol)-1) AS int), 
  CAST(SUBSTRING(myCol, CharINDEX('.', mycol)+1, 999) AS int)
```

Comment: Doesn't work - try putting a `1.2` in there: should appear after `1.0` but before `1.10`

Comment: This would cause 2.1 and 2.10 to be considered equivalent... and 2.3 would end up after 2.10.

Comment: That is aminor detail, the point is you can use CAST / CONVERT to order your elements, just use a substring.

Comment: Ok should work fine, i didnt originally notice the version number sorting mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SUBSTRING and CAST...

```
order by 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(DetailRefNumber, 0, 1) as int),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(DetailRefNumber, 2, LEN(DetailRefNumber) - 2) as int)
```

This will first order by the number before the decimal, then by the number after the decimal, and treat 2.10 as greater than 2.3.

Comment: This will force a table scan since `SUBSTRING` is not SARGable

Comment: Also this assumes the "whole" number is one digit. What happens when they get to `10.1`, `10.2`, etc.?

Comment: I meant it more as a starting point than a full copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  
from yourTable  
order by  
assessmentRefNum,  
convert(int,right(detailRefNum,len(detailRefNum)-charindex('.',detailRefNum,1)));
```

Comment: Did you try it? Like @Christian's answer this will also incorrectly sort `2.10` before `2.3` whether `assessmentRefNum` is string or numeric.

Comment: Yeah, I ran it with assessmentRefNum varchar(1) and detailRefNum varchar(5), the values sort properly. I would post an image but since I'm new I can't.